# Running a script at startup with rc.local (permission denied)

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts, startup

I prepared an image and included in `/etc/rc.local` a line to run a script:

```
/path/to/myscript.sh
```

I then created a script at that location

It contains a curl, to download and save a file as new file to the system. After this the file should be executed.

My problem is the following:

The content of the script I included directly to `rc.local` before and got an error `permission denied`.
It was the line downloading a scriptfile and save it locally.

Now I started to read further post and all said, it's better to exclude commands to a script file and launch the script file via rc.local only.

But the permissions-problem persists.

So I tried to modify my `rc.local` line:

```
/path/to/myscript.sh # not working
sudo /path/to/myscript.sh # not working
```

also in my script I added `sudo` to each command, it's not working.

Currently it seems curl with saving a file isn't allowed. (Internet connection exists).

Other posts say I should install a service.
Now I think it's going oversized and have no warranty. I need to run the script only once at reboot. In the script I tell the device to download bash-scripts and execute them.

So it seems I have a permission problem and I don't know how to fix it.

Maybe I used the wrong method to run a script after boot.

Why does this problem occur and how to fix ?

Comment: Are you sure that the script `/path/to/myscript.sh` is actually executable? What does `ls -l /path/to/myscript.sh` say?

Answer (score 4):

```
# ls test.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov 27 13:40 test.sh

# ./test.sh
-su: ./test.sh: permission denied
```

To solve:

```
# chmod +x test.sh
```

Change `test.sh` for `/path/to/myscript.sh`

Comment: Hmm you were a three year member with 1 point. Well now you have 11 points :)

Comment: Thanks! Will I get the 15 points in the next decade? ;)